# Use secrets in prometheus helm chart

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I am using the [promethues-community helm-charts](https://stackoverflow.com). I want to use azure_sd_configs as a scraper in my node_exporter job. It needs "client_secret" to authenticate with Azure but I can't find a way to pass the k8s secret to prometheus.yaml

What I tried:

```
  server:
    env:
      - name: AZURE_SD_CONFIGS_CLIENT_SECRET
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: service-credentials
            key: azure_sd_configs_client_secret
```

```
          azure_sd_configs:
            - environment: AzurePublicCloud
              port: 80
              subscription_id: xxx
              tenant_id: xxx
              client_id: xxx
              client_secret: ${AZURE_SD_CONFIGS_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

I can see the env var in the container but it does substitute it in prometheus.yaml.

Should this work? Is there a better way?

Thanks